# 'the label [1] is not in the [index]' error when using DataFrame loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, from which I want to select a cell. I can select a cell by a row index and column label, but when I filter dataframe, same selection doesn't work.

```
print("Title:",df.loc[1,'title']) # Has no error

mobiles = df.loc[df['cat3']=='mobile-phones']

print("Title:",mobiles.loc[1,'title']) # Has error
```

I get the following error for the last print:

```
KeyError: 'the label [1] is not in the [index]'
```

Comment: does this work if you do: `mobiles = df.loc[df['cat3']=='mobile-phones'].reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: index label 1 was probably filtered out. use `iloc` for index location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign mobiles as:

```
mobiles = df.loc[df['cat3']=='mobile-phones']
```

chances are there that `df['cat3']=='mobile-phones'` met the condition at indexes which is not 1.

Use:

```
mobiles = df.loc[df['cat3']=='mobile-phones'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or you can use `.iloc[]` to filter the first index(which doesnt see the label name)

Comment: for `iloc` I can't use the label index for columns, however, the first solution works.